# Borrowing money for investment

Tags: investing, interest, borrowing

What do you consider the best way to:

- Borrow money from private investors against a fixed interest rate
- Use it to trade, yielding a higher return than the interest rate
- Pay off the investors with profits gained

This strategy brings up a number of questions:

- Will a governing financial body allow you to borrow money for investment? Or will they see it as an activity "on behalf of" the lending investor?
- What would be the most suited location(s) to implement this strategy?

Comment: `Borrowing money for investment` The primary reason you need to find is why would somebody lend you the money to invest, considering there are already of glut of people and firms doing so. Are you sure you have the people behind you to lend you the capital ?

Comment: Do you have any capital to bring to the table, or are you asking the investor for 100% of the money to be used for trading? Do you have any experience trading with your own money?

Comment: And what happens if your investments lose money? If you have guaranteed a minimum rate of return, you take a big loss. And without the guaranteed rate of return, why should they deal with you rather than making their own investments?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, people deposit money with you, you agree to pay them fixed % back, and then you invest money for your own profit?

Sounds like a bank to me.  Or a dividend-paying mutual fund, or a number of other similar ideas.  Sure, you're welcome to start something like that up; it's unlikely you'd get money from people unless you had already proved yourself competent as an investor, though.  After all, if it's possible to get a safe, comfortable 5%, why would anyone give you money at 2% or 3% instead of just getting that 5% for themselves?  Or, more likely, finding a competitor who gives 4.9%?

As in most things, the market will find inefficiencies like this and squash them like bugs.

That said, there are some opportunities that take advantage of other kinds of situations.  The most common I'd say is owning a home.  You take out a mortgage for 80% of the value of the home, instead of buying it outright, and you instead invest the 80% in the market.  You likely will beat your mortgage rate given the current 3.5%-4% rates.  That's effectively doing the same thing, with an expense you'd have anyway (you always have to live somewhere); since it's a secured loan, you get better rates than the market will give (as it's quite safe) and you can use tax laws in your favor (mortgage interest deduction, in particular, and the capital gains break on primary residences).

Comment: Show me where you can get "a safe, comfortable 5%". :)

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I had not thought of the clever mortgage construction. It's clever because it lowers the source interest rate and widens the gap between what you earn and what you have to pay.

Also, I found two European countries that allow what's described in my question; Belgium and Liechtenstein.

Comment: I'm getting 5% from a CD right now. Admittedly that's a promotional rate.

Comment: And long-term, I'm getting market rate of return (at the moment averaging 8.75%) with near-zero effort with a mix of index funds rebalanced once a year or when I happen to notice they've drifted significantly from my intent. A mortgage can be the safest leveraged investment opportunity you will ever have, especially remembering that you might have the opportunity to refinace it to a lower rate later.

Answer (score 1):

What you're missing is that people can invest in the market directly without going through you. You haven't said anything that would make us even consider trusting you with our money, nor anything about how you plan to deliver better return to us than direct investment would when you are presumably going to be skimming profit off the top.

Yes, there is a business model here: Actively managed mutual funds are, essentially, exactly this. But they are backed by major financial institutions, they have a track record, they have experts on their team that they can point to, and in fact they struggle to produce sufficiently better investment results (compared to passively-managed index funds) to make up for the fees they demand.

It's nothing you can do as an individual unless you have something exceptional to offer the investors. And if you did, you wouldn't be asking us.